# Php apache mod rewrite remove .php not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to remove .php from my url,
below is my .htaccess contents

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /folder/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ path.php?username=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I don't have any idea what's going wrong.

Comment: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
checks for the existance of the file. If you have a home.php in the path, the rule will NOT match and thus load the file directly

Comment: @ stewe, I'm a beginner in mod rewrites, Basically i have two condition in my rules, first one is to clean url from **localhost/folder/profile?name=test** to **localhost/folder/test** and second one is to remove .php extension from url. I thought it's conflicting each other

Comment: So which URL isn't working for you?

Comment: rewrite rule to remove .php extension is not working

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an additional rule to redirect `.php URL` to non-php one. Try this code:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /folder/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ path.php?username=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+folder/(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```